# How to successfully call the submit when all validations are true

Tags: javascript

I have created a validation in javascript which detect if there's an empty field and if there's none then it will now insert into database which I use a PHP code.

But it does nothing I'm having trouble inserting into database, I think because I put `e.preventDefault()`, I put the `e.preventDefault()` so it will not reload and show the validation messages that I created.

```
(function() {

    document.querySelector('#addForm').onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = document.querySelector('#name');
    const age = document.querySelector('#age');
    const email = document.querySelector('#email');

    //Check empty input fields
    if(!document.querySelector('#name').value){
        name.classList.add('is-invalid');
    }else{
        name.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    }

    if(!document.querySelector('#age').value)
    {
        age.classList.add('is-invalid');
    }else{
        age.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    }

    if(!document.querySelector('#email').value){
        email.classList.add('is-invalid');
    }else{
        email.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    }

   }

})();
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You prevented the form from submitting

Comment: Yes I prevent it, but I don't know how to enable it again after the validations are false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only `e.preventDefault()` if any of the inputs are empty then, example updated:

```
document.querySelector('#addForm').onsubmit = function(e) {
    const name = document.querySelector('#name');
    const age = document.querySelector('#age');
    const email = document.querySelector('#email');
    let formIsInvalid = false;

    //Check empty input fields
    if (!name.value) {
        name.classList.add('is-invalid');
        formIsInvalid = true;
    } else {
        name.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    }

    if (!age.value) {
        age.classList.add('is-invalid');
        formIsInvalid = true;
    } else {
        age.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    }

    if (!email.value) {
        email.classList.add('is-invalid');
        formIsInvalid = true;
    } else {
        email.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    }

    if (formIsInvalid) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the shortest solution, thanks for enlightening how to use booleans more.. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You should append AJAX request to send values to the server

```
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Thank you!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
```